# Can "it" be used as "which" to represent what the previous sentence means?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> The priority is to lay down the moral base of this society: including ethical principles and political justice. It means that  what we are going to seek out and construct is the “republican virtue” which is a full virtue, concerning both institutional justice and individual duty.

Here I use "it" of the second sentence to represent the whole first sentence. It is equal to  "A. which means B...".
Can it be used in this way?

Answer (score 3):

No, the usage of 'it' by you doesn't make it clear that you are referring to the previous sentence.

You can use 'which', but a better choice would be to use '*this*'.

> The priority is to lay down the moral base of this society: including ethical principles and political justice. ***This*** means that what we are going to seek out and construct is the “republican virtue” which is a full virtue, concerning both institutional justice and individual duty.

Answer (score 1):

That is kind of hard for to get my mind around, as that it is pretty close to run-on sentence/thought. Can you break that down for me in a subject verb sort of way without presupposing, as referenced in Strunk&Wagners towards writing concise sentence structure. Or you just trying to get across a political view? Otherwise you can use any writing style and still communicate to the average.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your opinion. I will completely reorganize my thinking, and then rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but picture my Freshman High School English teacher clutching her Strunk and White and saying, "Omit needless words."

> **It means that what** we are going to seek out and construct is the
>   “republican virtue” which is a full virtue, concerning both
>   institutional justice and individual duty.

I would replace "It means that" with "As such."  You could also use "Therefore" or "Consequently" in the same way.

**As such**, what we are going to seek out and construct is ...

I would also reorganize the sentence so that it is active rather than passive.

> **As such**, we will seek out and construct the "Republican virtue" ...